# Getting percentage complete of an md5 checksum

Tags: python, cryptography, md5

I am currently getting an md5 checksum as follows:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> f = open(file)
>>> m = hashlib.md5()
>>> m.update(f.read())
>>> checksum = m.hedxigest()
```

I need to return the checksum of a large video file, that will take several minutes to generate. How would I implement a percentage counter, such that it prints the percentage complete for each percentage while it is running. Something like:

```
>>> checksum = m.hedxigest()
1% done...
2% done...
etc.
```

Comment: the `hashlib` has a `digest_size()` function that can return the size of resulting hash in bytes. You can compare this size to the size that the md5 hash will be once complete to get the percentage done.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen No you can't. MD5 digests are fixed-length, they don't get longer as the input text does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call the `update()` method repeatedly and feed the file in chunks to it. Thus, you can show the progress yourself.

```
import hashlib
import os

def digest_with_progress(filename, chunk_size):
    read_size = 0
    last_percent_done = 0
    digest = hashlib.md5()
    total_size = os.path.getsize(filename)

    data = True
    f = open(filename)
    while data:
        # Read and update digest.
        data = f.read(chunk_size)
        read_size += len(data)
        digest.update(data)

        # Calculate progress.
        percent_done = 100 * read_size / total_size
        if percent_done > last_percent_done:
            print '%d%% done' % percent_done
            last_percent_done = percent_done
    f.close()
    return digest.hexdigest()
```

When I try `print digest_with_progress('/bin/bash', 1024)` this is what I get:

```
1% done
2% done
3% done
4% done
5% done
6% done
7% done
8% done
9% done
10% done
11% done
12% done
13% done
14% done
15% done
16% done
17% done
18% done
19% done
20% done
21% done
22% done
23% done
24% done
25% done
26% done
27% done
28% done
29% done
30% done
31% done
32% done
33% done
34% done
35% done
36% done
37% done
38% done
39% done
40% done
41% done
42% done
43% done
44% done
45% done
46% done
47% done
48% done
49% done
50% done
51% done
52% done
53% done
54% done
55% done
56% done
57% done
58% done
59% done
60% done
61% done
62% done
63% done
64% done
65% done
66% done
67% done
68% done
69% done
70% done
71% done
72% done
73% done
74% done
75% done
76% done
77% done
78% done
79% done
80% done
81% done
82% done
83% done
84% done
85% done
86% done
87% done
88% done
89% done
90% done
91% done
92% done
93% done
94% done
95% done
96% done
97% done
98% done
99% done
100% done
b114ecaab65bc5b02f5a129bd29d1864
```

Here are the actual details of this file.

```
$ ls -l /bin/bash; md5sum /bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 971384 Nov 30 16:31 /bin/bash
b114ecaab65bc5b02f5a129bd29d1864  /bin/bash
```

Note that, you would not get the expected output if you make `chunk_size` too large. For example if we read in 100 KB chunks instead of 1 KB chunks for `/bin/bash`, this is what you see.

```
10% done
21% done
31% done
42% done
52% done
63% done
73% done
84% done
94% done
100% done
b114ecaab65bc5b02f5a129bd29d1864
```

The limitation of this approach is that we calculate the progress only after we have read a chunk into the digest. So, if the chunk size is too large, the percentage-difference in progress would be more than 1% every time you read a chunk and update the digest. A bigger chunk size would get the job done a bit quicker. So, you might want to relax the condition of printing percentage complete for each percentage in favour of efficiency.

Comment: FWIW, I'd read a bit more than 50 bytes at a time. 16-64 k or so.

Answer (score 4):

You should read the file in chunks with `f.read(N_BYTES)`, keep track of how far in the file you are, and pass the chunks to `m.update`. That's the expensive operation, not `md5.hexdigest`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's not the `hedxigest()` call that'll take a while, it's the reading of the file that will.

With this in mind, replace `m.update(f.read())` with a loop where you read the file block by block, update the checksum, and periodically print out a progress report.